# How to display multiple forms per entity in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm facing a logical problem :
Let's say I have a class foo, foo_linked_object_1 and foo_linked_object_2. The relationships are:

- foo 1------m foo_linked_object_1
- foo 1------m foo_linked_object_2

What I'm trying to do is to have a view, displaying all informations about some foo objects (so far so good) AND, below each foo, two forms that allow me to create a foo_linked_object_1 or foo_linked_object_2.

I've tried the following solution:

forms.py

```
CreateFLO1(Form):
    #FLO fields ...

CreateFLO2(Form):
    #FLO2 fields ...
```

controller.py

```
@app.route('/foo/<param>')
def foo_per_param(param):
    foos = Foo.query.filter_by(param=param)
    for foo in foos:
        foo.FLO1Form = CreateFLO1()
        foo.FLO2Form = CreateFLO2()
    return render_template('foo.html', foos=foos)
```

foo.html

```
{% for foo in foos %}
    {{ foo.infos }} <! -- etc etc -->
    {{ foo.FLO1Form.field1 }}
    {{ foo.FLO1Form.field2 }} <! -- etc etc, same for FLO2Form -->
```

Jinja returns me the following error :

> UndefinedError: app.models.foo.Foo object has no attribute 'FLO1Form'

Does anyone know how I would link those forms with each entity ?

Comment: `foos = Foo.query.filter_by(param=param)` this returns a query object instead the result set. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think so. How am I supposed to get the result set ? @metmirr : just found the solution ... I just need to add .all() right ? Feel a bit stupid ._.

Comment: Use `all()` `foos = Foo.query.filter_by(param=param).all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Metmirr :

I wasn't getting the right information.

```
Entity.query.filter_by(param=param)
```

returns a query object, whereas

```
Entity.query.filter_by(param=param).all()
```

returns the result set. Thanks !